# MVC 5 web api routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Hello I make a mvc 5 wep api like, now I wanna make a source like this "/countries/{countryId}/cities" to a list of cities from a country.

This is the method:

```
[Route("countries/{id}/cities")]
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<CityDTO> Cities(int id)
{
           //todo
}
```

The default rout config was like this:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
     name: "DefaultApi",    
     routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",    
     defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional } 
);
```

HelpPAge:

[image]

Then I added a new routing config like this:

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
              name: "ActionBasedApi",
              routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}/{action}",
             defaults: new { controller = "Countries", action = "Cities", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
          );
```

But now my HelpPage apear like this:

[image]

And when i call make GET to "/countries/{countryId}" to get just one country, I get this error:

**"Multiple actions were found that match the request:.."**

Somenoe can helpme to solve this, geting a routing that I Want?

**EDIT**
This is the entire CountryController class

```
 public class CountriesController : BaseController
    {
        // GET: api/Countries
        public IEnumerable<CountryDTO> Get()
        {
            using (var respository = new CountryRepository())
            {
                var countries = respository.GetAll().ToList();
                return countries.Map<List<CountryDTO>, List<Erp360.DataAccess.Country>>();
            }
        }



        // GET: api/Countries/5
        public CountryDTO Get(int id)
        {
            using (var respository = new CountryRepository())
            {
                var countries = respository.GetAll().FirstOrDefault(c => c.CountryId == id);
                return countries.Map<CountryDTO, DataAccess.Country>();
            }
        }


        // GET: api/Countries/5
        [Route("countries/cities/{id}")]
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<CityDTO> Cities(int id)
        {
            using (var respository = new CityRepository())
            {
                var cities = respository.GetFiltered(c => c.CountryId == id).ToList();
                return cities.Map<List<CityDTO>, List<DataAccess.City>>();
            }
        }

        // POST: api/Countries
        public void Post([FromBody]CountryDTO value)
        {
            using (var repository = new CountryRepository())
            {
                var country = ManageInput(value);
                repository.Add(country);
                repository.Save();

            }
        }

        // PUT: api/Countries/5
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody]CountryDTO value)
        {
            using (var repository = new CountryRepository())
            {
                var country = ManageInput(value);
                repository.Modify(country);
                repository.Save();
            }
        }

        // DELETE: api/Countries/5
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
            using (var repository = new CountryRepository())
            {
                var country = repository.Get(id);
                repository.Remove(country);
                repository.Save();
            }
        }


        private DataAccess.Country ManageInput(CountryDTO value)
        {
            var country = value.Map<Core.BusinessModel.Country, CountryDTO>();

            if (!IsValid(country))
                return null;

            return country.Map<DataAccess.Country, Core.BusinessModel.Country>();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, maybe you get this error because you have two actions in your controller that can be call with a GET and have a similar structure? Can you show us the others actions that you have?

Answer (score 0):

please be sure that you have enable the attribute routing, in the routes config, add the following line before the config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(...)

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

There are a few potential issues here.

First of all, you need to ensure the longer route occurs *before* the shorter route.

Secondly, you cannot put an optional segment ("id") followed by a required segment. In fact, if you want the route only for the purpose of having 1 additional segment, you should make all of its segments required.

```
// This route matches any 4 segment route beginning with api/
// 3 segments will not match
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ActionBasedApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}/{action}"
);

// This route will match any 2 or 3 segment route beginning with api/
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",    
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",    
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional } 
);
```

Third, you should remove the attribute route if you have created a general route that serves the same purpose.